# how to make the the elements follow the text below

Tags: html, css

I have a problem, I am confused about how to make the label always follow the text below it, initially I used absolute position and the label followed the text, but the text did not always dock at the bottom of the div, then I used this code to finally succeed. but the label does not follow the text below. Do you have a way?

```css
img {width:100%;}
a{color:white;}
.post-thumb{position: relative;}
.post-title {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   margin:25px
   }
.label-info {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 35px;
   left: 0;
   margin:25px;
   background:red;
   padding:10px;
   }
```

```html
<div class="post-thumb">

<h2 class="post-title">
<a href="#">Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem...</a>
</h2>

<span class="label-info">
<a href="https://vhlankampus.blogspot.com/search/label/Military?max-results=7" rel="tag">Military</a>
</span>

<a href="#">
<img src="//3.bp.blogspot.com/-WGexrTyXadk/VffXDzFgS7I/AAAAAAAAPC8/pufmqdU_G_I/s1600/world_cop-and-student_428K.jpg"/>
</a>
</div>
```

[image: I describe in this picture]

Comment: Please keep in mind, if one of the answers works for you, please mark them as the answer to help other peeps in the community to find their solution easier if they facing the same issue. You can do this by using grey marks (tick) beside answers (you can only choose one), for more information please read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by **manipulating your HTML structure**. So **you need to wrap your text and button into the same parent `div`** then reorder the `label-info` and `post-title` and then assign all `post-title` style to new parent `div` and get rid of `label-info` positioning.

So it will be something like this:

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}

a {
  color: white;
}

.post-thumb {
  position: relative;
}

.post-info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 25px
}

.label-info {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-thumb">

  <div class="post-info">
    <span class="label-info">
<a href="https://vhlankampus.blogspot.com/search/label/Military?max-results=7" rel="tag">Military</a>
</span>
    <h2 class="post-title">
      <a href="#">Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem
    Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem
    Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem...</a>
    </h2>
  </div>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="//3.bp.blogspot.com/-WGexrTyXadk/VffXDzFgS7I/AAAAAAAAPC8/pufmqdU_G_I/s1600/world_cop-and-student_428K.jpg" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using absolute positioning, the elements wont care if something is in the way and just appear on top of each other.

Put both the elements into a div like so:

```
 <div class="post-info-container">
    
    <span class="label-info">
    <a href="https://vhlankampus.blogspot.com/search/label/Military?max-results=7" rel="tag">Military</a>
    </span>
    <h2 class="post-title">
        <a href="#">Neque porro quisquam est qui doloremdasdaskl;djawildjaskl...</a>
        </h2>
    </div>
```

Change your `post-title` and `label-info` classes like this:

```
.post-title {
   margin:25px
   }
.label-info {
   margin:25px;
   background:red;
   padding:10px;
   }
```

Then add the `post-info-container` class:

```
.post-info-container {
        position: absolute;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/udn7jpfL/ here is a solution.

Wrap `.post-title, .label-info` inside of div with `position:absolute`.

```
<div class="info">
  <span class="label-info">
    <a href="https://vhlankampus.blogspot.com/search/label/Military?max-results=7" rel="tag">Military</a>
  </span>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <h2 class="post-title">
    <a href="#">Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem...<br/>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem...</a>
  </h2>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

```
.info {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   padding-bottom:25px;
}
   
.label-info {
   background:red;
   padding:10px;
   }
   
   .post-title, .label-info{
     display:block;
     float:left;
     margin:0 25px 25px 25px;
   }
   
   .clear{
     clear:both;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this, I normally try to use a wrapper. In this example, I switched the label and the title in the HTML, so they just use normal flow.

```
<div class="post-thumb">
    <div class="label-wrapper">
        <span class="label-info">
            <a href="https://vhlankampus.blogspot.com/search/label/Military?max-results=7" rel="tag">Military</a>
        </span>
        
        <h2 class="post-title">
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus minus nostrum tempora hic exercitationem temporibus voluptatum dolores laboriosam nihil. Nihil at necessitatibus voluptate? Sed, sunt voluptates odit atque repellendus perspiciatis!</a>
        </h2>
    </div>
    
    <a href="#">
        <img src="//3.bp.blogspot.com/-WGexrTyXadk/VffXDzFgS7I/AAAAAAAAPC8/pufmqdU_G_I/s1600/world_cop-and-student_428K.jpg"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

```
img {width:100%;}
a{color:white;}
.post-thumb{position: relative;}
.post-title {
   margin:25px
}

.label-info {
   margin:25px;
   background:red;
   padding:10px;
}

.label-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: fit-content;
}
```